# How to put multiple services in one class which implement JavaDelegate inteface in Activiti

Tags: java, activiti

I use Activiti 6.x as my workflow engine, each service task node should bind to a class which implement JavaDelegate interface. Since there're more than 200 services in my project, if one class only contains one service, I have to create more than 200 classes, it's not sensible. Is there a way that I can put multiple services in one class? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look in the docs (activiti.org).. but i think that you can also use beans from spring.. that means that you can point to different methods of the same bean.